# How to eliminate equal lines in a file

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran90

I have a file.txt such as follow:

```
1. 0. 3.21
1. 1. 2.11
1. 2. 1.554
1. 0. 3.21
1. 3. 1.111
1. 2. 1.554
```

As you can see I have two lines that are equal one to another (the first and the fourth and the third and the sixth). My attempt is to eliminate the lines that are equals to obtain something like:

```
1. 0. 3.21
1. 1. 2.11
1. 2. 1.554
1. 3. 1.111
```

My try of a fortran program to do it is:

```
        program mean
        implicit none
        integer :: i,j,n,s,units
        REAL*8,allocatable::  x(:),y(:),amp(:)

            ! open the file I want to change

            OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='oldfile.dat')
            n=0
            DO
              READ(10,*,END=100)          
              n=n+1
            END DO

     100     continue
             rewind(10)
        allocate(x(n),y(n),amp(n))
    s=0

       ! save the numbers from the file in three different vectors

        do s=1, n
          read(10,*) x(s), y(s),amp(s)
        end do
       !---------------------!

    ! Open the file that should contains the new data without repetition       
    units=107
    open(unit=units,file='newfile.dat')

    ! THIS SHOULD WRITE ONLY NOT EQUAL ELEMENTS of THE oldfile.dat:
    ! scan the elements in the third column and write only the elements for which
    ! the if statement is true, namely: write only the elements (x,y,amp) that have
    ! different values in the third column. 

    do i=1,n
      do j = i+1,n
        if (amp(i) .ne. amp(j)) then ! 
         write(units,*),x(j),y(j),amp(j)
        end if
      end do
    end do   
   end program
```

But the output file looks like that:

```
   1.000000       1.000000       2.110000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000    
   1.000000       3.000000       1.111000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000    
   1.000000      0.0000000E+00   3.210000    
   1.000000       3.000000       1.111000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000    
   1.000000      0.0000000E+00   3.210000    
   1.000000       3.000000       1.111000    
   1.000000       3.000000       1.111000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000    
   1.000000       2.000000       1.554000
```

I don't understand what is the problem with the `if` condition, could You so kind to help me a bit?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's a lot better.  Now, is the input file you've posted exactly representative of the real input file ?  And how many lines would there be in a typical input file ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes is exactly the same a matrix of three real-type columns and n rows in which n=100000 (more or less this is the general number of lines of an output).

Comment: whatever the algorithm consider doing the whole thing using string operations (assuming "equal" lines are equal in their text representation). It will simplify the code, could be faster, and your output will be automatically formatted the same as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't fix your approach I'd drop it completely.  What you've got is an `O(n^2)` algorithm, adequate for small numbers of lines but on `10^5` lines you're going to execute the `if` statement `0.5 * 10^10` times.  Fortran's fast but that's needlessly wasteful.

I would first sort the file (`O(n log n)`) then scan it (`O(n)`) and eliminate duplicates.  And I probably wouldn't use Fortran to sort it, I'd use one of the Linux utilities such as `sort`.  Then I'd probably use `uniq`, and end up doing no Fortran programming at all.

If you want to write the deduplicated file out in the original order then I'd add a line number, then sort, uniqueify, then re-sort.

I believe that recent editions of Windows, ones which support the Powershell, have equivalent commands.

And if I absolutely had to do all this in Fortran I'd write a sort routine (or, rather, pull one out of my bag of tricks) and get on with it.  I'd be inclined to read the lines as strings and sort them textually, no messing around with reals and their tricky concept of equality.  For `10^5` lines I'd read the entire file into an array, sort it into another array, then carry on.

Finally, I think the logic of your `if` statement is wonky.  It decides whether or not to write a line to the new file based solely on the equality (or not) of the third field, i.e. of `amp`.  It should surely consider all three fields on lines `i` and `j`, more like

```
if ( any( [ x(i)/=x(j), y(i)/=y(j), amp(i)/=amp(j) ] ) ) then
```

Comment: it's working ! And it's work pretty good and fast. I sort the file with `sort -n -k 3 oldfile.txt >> sort.txt` to have all equal numbers of the third line one under the others. Then I just use `uniq sort.txt >> newfile.txt` and that's it ! Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just to repair the brute force loop, it should be something like this:

```
do i=1,n
  j=1
  do while( j.lt.i.and.amp(i) .ne. amp(j))
    j=j+1
  enddo
  if(j.eq.i)write(units,*)x(i),y(i),amp(i)
end do
```

or

```
do i=1,n
  do j=1,i-1
   if ( amp(i) .eq. amp(j) ) exit
  enddo
  if(j.eq.i)write(units,*)x(i),y(i),amp(i)
end do
```